# What is Simple Logging Facade for Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, slf4j, slf4j-api

Im a newbie and while watching a youtube tutorial for recommender system, I came across SLFJ. What is it ?

Comment: You shouldn't ask questions which can be easily searched in "Seach Engines."I have made this mistake many times.Try to rectify it the next time you post your question in this community.

Answer (score 1):

**Definition:**

> The Simple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4J) serves as a simple facade or abstraction for various logging frameworks (e.g. java.util.logging, logback, log4j) allowing the end user to plug in the desired logging framework at deployment time.

**Source:**

https://www.slf4j.org/

Answer (score 0):

See Wikipedia [Facade pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern):

> A facade is an object that provides a simplified interface to a larger body of code, such as a class library.

Specifically, `SLF4J` exposes an interface to your code that allows you to change your logging mechanism without changing your code.

Using it you can write code that generates log entries that runs in almost all situations.